# Storing output of MYSQL command in variable in UNIX Bash shell

Tags: unix

I am having issue in storing output of MYSQL command in variable in UNIX Bash shell

```
   db_out= $(mysql -u$MASTER_DB_USER -p$MASTER_DB_PASSWD -P$MASTER_DB_PORT -h$MASTER_DB_HOST -D$MASTER_DB_NAME<<Enf
    show databases;
    Enf)

echo $db_out
```

I am getting no output in variable $db_out.

Can some body suggest what is missing in above query?

having below **output**:

```
 db_out= mysql -u$MASTER_DB_USER -p$MASTER_DB_PASSWD -P$MASTER_DB_PORT -h$MASTER_DB_HOST      -D$MASTER_DB_NAME --execute "show databases"
           + db_out=
          + mysql -uroot -paxway -P3306 -h10.151.14.248 -Dsentinel --execute 'show databases'
  +--------------------+
  | Database           |
  +--------------------+
  +--------------------+

  | information_schema |
  | composer           |
  | mysql              |
  | sentinel           |
  | test               |
  +--------------------+
  echo "$db_out"
  + echo ''
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the output is written to STDERR.

try:

```
db_out= $(mysql -u$MASTER_DB_USER -p$MASTER_DB_PASSWD -P$MASTER_DB_PORT -h$MASTER_DB_HOST -D$MASTER_DB_NAME 2>&1 <<Enf
show databases;
Enf)
```

or:

```
db_out= $( echo "show databases;" | mysql -u$MASTER_DB_USER -p$MASTER_DB_PASSWD -P$MASTER_DB_PORT -h$MASTER_DB_HOST -D$MASTER_DB_NAME 2>&1)
```